# What is the use case for declaration merging?

Tags: typescript

I'm reading a bit about [declaration merging](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) in TypeScript and I have a hard time grokking the use case for it, specifically for interfaces.

In their documentation, they have this example:

> That is, in the example:
>
> ```
> interface Cloner {
>     clone(animal: Animal): Animal;
> }
>
> interface Cloner {
>     clone(animal: Sheep): Sheep;
> }
>
> interface Cloner {
>     clone(animal: Dog): Dog;
>     clone(animal: Cat): Cat;
> }
> ```
>
> The three interfaces will merge to create a single declaration as so:
>
> ```
> interface Cloner {
>     clone(animal: Dog): Dog;
>     clone(animal: Cat): Cat;
>     clone(animal: Sheep): Sheep;
>     clone(animal: Animal): Animal;
> }
> ```

Why would one want to create three separate interfaces instead of the resulting declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, you might want to add a method to the window object, so you'll do this:

```
interface Window {
    myMethod(): string;
}

window.myMethod = function() {
    ...
}
```

This is very useful when you need to polyfill:

```
interface String {
    trimLeft(): string;
    trimRight(): string;
}

if (!String.prototype.trimLeft) {
    String.prototype.trimLeft = function() { ... }
}

if (!String.prototype.trimRight) {
    String.prototype.trimRight = function() { ... }
}
```

Comment: So it's simply for extending existing interfaces that one does not, otherwise, have access to? Would there ever be a case for writing your own duplicate declarations?

Comment: That's one use case, but you are welcome to extend your own types as well. For example, let's say you have one module which defined interface `MyInterface`, but then you might load another module which, when loaded, extends this `MyInterface`

Comment: That won't work.. this works: declare global{
    interface String {
        trimLeft(): string;

        trimRight(): string;
    }
}